# parquet-mr versions are coming different for various Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet-mr

We have created Shell script and from the Shell Script we are using Spark submit command to call HQL files. But for multiple hive tables, parquet-mr versions are coming differently(1.6.0,1.8.1,1.8.2).

Please find our stack details

- EMR version: 5.8
- Spark: 2.2
- Hive:2.3.0

Could anyone help me to understand how these Parquet MR versions are getting different for different tables?

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. you mean different hive tables have different `parquet-mr` versions?

Comment: Yes different Hive tables are having different parquet-mr versions.